# Select2 version 4 and above not working to get data result

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I have this following **javaScript** which it's working well with **Select2** version below 4, so, now I'm going to upgrade it to version 4.0.7 but it doesn't work. could you please guide me how to solve it?

```
    $(".locations").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        width: '100%',
        maximumSelectionSize: 1,
        ajax:{
            url: "My_URL_HERE",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function(term) {
                return { q:term }
            },
            results:function(data) {
                return { results: data }
            }
        }
    });

        $(".locations").on("select2-selecting",function(e){
        $("input[name=module_type]").val(e.object.module);
        $("input[name=select2-search__field]").val(e.object.id);
        $("input[name=slug]").val(e.object.id);
        });
```

and this is my Input code:

```
    <input type="text" name="name" class="locations">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you shoud use `select` instead of `input`:

```
<select name="name" class="locations"></select>
```

Read more: [Select2 Ajax (remote data)](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)

Comment: I used select but no result found. As I mentioned, In previous Select2 version, it's working well.

Comment: try `processResults:function(data)...` instead of `results:function(data)...`

Comment: I've tested too, doesn't work, processResults:function(data) { return { results: data } }